# What sets the appearance of the "done" button for fullscreen IME soft keyboard?

Tags: android

Recently I was surprised to see a "Done" button appear next to a multiline EditText when I tapped it in Landscape mode.    Several helpful S.O. posters explained that this is default behaviour when the soft keyboard obscures so much of the UI that there's hardly room for anything but the EditText itself.

So my question is this:  the default "Done" button is a generic button with a generic font on a gray background.  It doesn't resemble or coordinate with the soft keyboard or with my app.    How can I style the button, its color and font, so I can make its appearance fit in with everything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect this is controlled either by the IME or the system. If so, then I don't think you can do anything about it.

Comment: The fullscreen (Extracted EditText) UI is created by system, not by host App nor by IME so there is very little you can do.